# Sum of column values dynamically mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating view which selects various number of columns from the various tables accumulating numerous columns in the view
say

```
col1, col2,..............,coln
```

When i need sum of all these columns I need to write as

```
SELECT col1+col2+............+coln FROM myview
```

I want trick that I can get the sum without have to mentioning all the column name.

Comment: Nope . . . there is no such trick in SQL.  You problem is probably that you have stored values in columns where there should be one row per value, rather than one column per value.  Then you could use `sum()`.

Comment: There is no SQL shorthand for what you are trying to achieve. Can't be done.

Comment: If the datatype of all the columns fetched is same, then as @GordonLinoff says, you should fetch them as rows instead of columns. You can achieve this (fetch as rows) by using SELECT with UNION clause.

Comment: @SameerMirji - so there is no any way????

Comment: @Mr.Arjun: Considering all the columns have same datatype, no other way than doing this: `SELECT col1 AS col FROM x UNION SELECT col2 as col FROM y .... UNION SELECT col3 as col FROM n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL to do this: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html
An example:

```
SELECT concat( 'SELECT ', group_concat( COLUMN_NAME SEPARATOR '+' ),
                ' FROM ', 'myview' )
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'myview'
INTO @s;
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

A working demo on SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4835b/1